# animate transition to child view controller

Tags: ios, swift

[example booking](https://gfycat.com/annualidolizedgreatargus)

How can I animate transition to child view controller, as Booking animate, example you can see above.

my code :

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    addChild(viewController)
    mainView.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

    viewController.view.frame = mainView.containerView.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

I try :

```
UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }, completion: nil)
```

but I can't find the right animation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the following:

1. Transform the container view, so that it is outside the screen. You can either manipulate constraints or use `CGAffineTransform`, like this:

```swift
mainView.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
```

2. Call `add(asChildViewController: viewController)`
3. Move the container back to screen. If you manipulated constraints in step 1, do it again. If you used `CGAffineTransform`, just write:

```swift
mainView.containerView.transform = .identity
```

When you want to animate the transition, just wrap it like this:

```swift
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: duration,
    delay: 0,
    options: .curveEaseInOut,
    animations: {
        mainView.containerView.transform = .identity
    }
)
```

Make sure that you do not add multiple child view controller on top of each other. You can either remove child view controller every time you hide it (if it intended to be a different view controller each time it appears) or you can call `add(asChildViewController: viewController)` once in `viewDidLoad` and then only repeat steps 1 and 3 every time you need to show and hide the child view controller.

Comment: thx, this help for me, but when there is animation between containers I see empty space, can this be fixed ?

Comment: I add screen with empty space when animate between containers

Comment: Did you use constraints or CGAffineTransform?